# Can a single jQuery line be written to perform this hide and fadein?

Tags: jquery

An easy question for a jQuery guru!

This jQuery and Javascript mix works fine,

```
function fadeInResponseMsg(msg)
{
    $("#responsemsg").hide();
    document.getElementById("responsemsg").innerHTML = msg;
    $("#responsemsg").fadeIn(); 
}
```

I'm learning jQuery so I'd like to know if it be written in a single line?

I have tried this but it wont work.

```
$("#responsemsg").hide().val(msg).fadeIn();
```

I'd prefer not to spend another few hours reading around, so help is appreciated.

Thanks for the quick answer all...

fyi the HTML

```
<table><tr><td class="responsemsg" id="responsemsg">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Is `responsemsg` a div element or what? Since the `.val()` method is primarily used to get/set the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$("#responsemsg").hide().html(msg).fadeIn();
```

But the very first search for "jQuery innerHTML" returns that documentation page, so consider refining your search skills in order not to spend *hours*! : ))

Comment: @RenéGeuze "This method uses the browser's innerHTML property." Since the OP originally had `innerHTML`, `html()` is the proper function, not `text()` or `val()`.

Comment: @jbabey, correct. But take into consideration that a lot of people will use innerHTML for just text. And using .html when you just ever have text is 'wrong'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Comment: I did spend some time looking around, there are answers that use opacity, questions of browser compatibility etc.. sometimes you cant see what is under your nose;

Answer (score 1):

Like so you want to use jQuerys `html` http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$("#responsemsg")
     .hide()
     .html(msg)
     .fadeIn();
```

in one line

```
$("#responsemsg").hide().html(msg).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#responsemsg").hide().html(msg).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var msg = 'this is a new response message...';

    $('#responsemsg').hide().html( msg ).fadeIn();
});
```

[Test it here...](http://jsfiddle.net/r5hWH/)